# Chromium ignores z-index property on iframes

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, iframe, chromium

I'm on Windows and I have a strange problem.
I believe it's a `Chromium` bug, but (1) I can't find any information about it and (2) it happens on IE9 too...

It seems that I can **not** place any element over and iFrame and still make it visible. That is, the iFrame is always over any other `DOM` element in the page.
To its practical extent, it means that an iFrame has a `z-index = infinite`.

Any clues on how to solve this (a workaround will be nice as long as it doesn't change much code) or more information on the subject?

This doesn't happen in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, so it's not utterly important.

This is a problem I have in a website I created to browse YouTube videos, **[YouTubeGo](http://YouTubeGo.net/funny-cats)**, and the full screen embed (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, or click on the fullscreen icon at the top left) just lays over the search results and the input box. Which, of course, shouldn't happen.

Thank you!